# MultipartRequestEntity: Specifying the content type of a FilePart

Tags: groovy, multipart, jira-rest-api

I am working with JIRA REST API and I'm trying to upload an image to be used as an avatar.

My image is a JPEG file but I get this error.

> The file content you have provided is not a supported image format. Please try a JPEG, GIF or PNG file.

This is how I declare my FilePart:

```
Part[] part = [ new FilePart( 'avatar', imgToUpload ) ]
```

How do you specify the file type? Is this correct?

```
Part[] part = [ new FilePart( 'avatar', imgToUpload, 'image/jpeg', null ) ]
```

Thanks.

EDIT: This is what worked.

```
def filePart = new Filepart( 'avatar', imgToUpload )
filePart.setContentType( 'image/jpeg' )
filePart.setCharSet( null )
Part[] part = [ filePart ]
```

Comment: Check if the link helps http://www.massapi.com/class/fi/FilePart.html

Comment: Thanks but no, I didn't find anything.

Comment: Just for clarity: we're talking about this method: [jira/rest/api/2/user/avatar/temporary](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4553) ?

Comment: I'm trying to use /rest/api/2/project/{projectIdOrKey}/avatar/temporary first.

Comment: I imagine they probably work the same way.